# How to Integrate Facebook sdk for android development on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I am relatively new to Eclipse IDE and want to build facebook login option in my android app. I looked up *developers.facebook* documentation but can't find one for *Eclipse IDE* (they have it for *Android Studio*). So i want to know if it is possible? (if yes then how could it be done?)

Comment: this is one of the reason that make me migrate to AS...

Comment: @g2o right! but still it would be cool if it could be done on eclipse!